# ubuntu 18.04 no sound output from any audio device, following bluetooth connection

Tags: drivers, sound, bluetooth, alsa, hp

My Ubuntu system has stopped producing any sound what-so-ever, since I used a set of Bluetooth headphones with it, though the Bluetooth may be unrelated, it was just the last thing I used.

**First the obvious:** No the headphones are not still connected, and Bluetooth is switched off. It is not muted in the system tray, and i do not have the program making the sound muted. I have tried several sources including the sound test in settings/sound. I have done both `sudo apt-get update` and `sudo apt-get upgrade` as well as rebooted the system.

**I have also tried**:

1. `alsamixer` shows the audio channels to be not unmuted and with volume, also auto-mute is disabled.
2. `pavucontrol` shows several port options (*headphones*, *speakers* and *line out*) ports. Each showing a volume metre that is responsive to the audio sources on the computer, and the *line out* and *headphones* ports are responsive to having something plugged into them; registering plugged in/unplugged but no sound through either.
3. input devices in both the sound tab of settings, and `pavucontrol` is responsive to sounds I make, so it appears the microphone is working.
4. I have reinstalled pulseaudio and alsa-base using

```
sudo apt remove --purge alsa-base pulseaudio
sudo apt install alsa-base pulseaudio
```

as well as reloading alsa with

```
sudo alsa force-reload
```

---

Everything appears perfectly normal, except I get no sound output from speakers or headphones.

Comment: To check if the problem is some configuration in your user profile, try creating another user and login with that user. If sound works there, then at least you know that there's something in `~/.config` or some other folder there that's causing the issue.

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar issue once and what solved it was resetting Pulseaudio to default settings.

You may try: `mv ~/.config/pulse ~/.config/pulse.bak` and rebooting or logging out and then in again.

If sound returns, then you may delete the pulse.bak file `rm ~/.config/pulse.bak`

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I tried, this and had seen it as a potential solution elsewhere. Did not solve the problem for me though.

Answer (score 0):

So I managed to finally get the sound working by re-installing the HDA sound drivers for my machine using

```
sudo apt install linux-modules-extra-`uname -r`
```

seen [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/1193873/905346).

At least i believe this was the solution. Sound just started working, and this was the last significant thing i remember doing. Would be great if someone could confirm this as a probable solution.

To anyone experiencing similar issues, you can check your sound drivers using `inxi -A`.