# 18.04 No sound - Intel sound card snd_hda_intel not working

Tags: drivers, nvidia, hardware, intel, soundcard

```
$ aplay -l

**** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
card 1: NVidia [HDA NVidia], device 3: HDMI 0 [HDMI 0]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0


$ cat /proc/asound/modules

1 snd_hda_intel

$ lspci -v | grep -A7 -i "audio"

00:1f.3 Multimedia audio controller: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH cAVS (rev 10)
    Subsystem: Dell Device 0949
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 32, IRQ 16
    Memory at a5318000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
    Memory at a5000000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=1M]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: snd_soc_skl
    Kernel modules: snd_hda_intel, snd_soc_skl, sof_pci_dev


01:00.1 Audio device: NVIDIA Corporation GP107GL High Definition Audio Controller (rev a1)
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 17
    Memory at a3080000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel
    Kernel modules: snd_hda_intel
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You will need to add an option on GRUB.

To edit grub options:

```
sudo nano /etc/default/grub
```

Find `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT` and add `snd_hda_intel.dmic_detect=0` to the end of it. It will look something like this:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="loglevel=3 snd_hda_intel.dmic_detect=0"
```

Then rebuild grub menu:

```
sudo grub-mkconfig -o /boot/grub/grub.cfg
```

After you reboot the system the device should work.

Comment: Thank You! It worked perfectly.

Comment: Wont this basically disable the HD drivers for input ?

Answer (score 2):

For me the solution was to install the latest Sound Open Firmware (SOF) binaries from here: https://github.com/thesofproject/sof-bin

Specifically:

1. Clone the repository: `git clone https://github.com/thesofproject/sof-bin.git`
2. Change to directory: `cd sof-bin`
3. Follow: https://github.com/thesofproject/sof-bin#install-process-with-installsh (for me v2.2 worked)

```
sudo mv /lib/firmware/intel/sof* some_backup_location/
sudo mv /usr/local/bin/sof-*     some_backup_location/ # optional
sudo ./install.sh v2.2.x/v2.2
```

4. Reboot

After this the sound output as well as the microphone were working (Ubuntu 23.04, Lenovo X1 Gen8)

Note: Make sure that the `snd_hda_intel.dmic_detect=0` or `snd_intel_dspcfg.dsp_driver=1` settings are not set in `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT` or `/etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf`. Otherwise the sound output may work but no microphone input.

Related question/answer: https://askubuntu.com/a/1424600/142531