# No sound on new lubuntu install on a chromebook

Tags: drivers, sound, pulseaudio, alsa, chromebook

Device is an Asus Chromebook.

Soundcard is detected by lspci:

```
jasper@crbook1:~$ lspci -v | grep -A7 -i "audio"
00:0e.0 Multimedia audio controller: Intel Corporation Celeron N3350/Pentium N4200/Atom E3900 Series Audio Cluster (rev 0b)
        Subsystem: Intel Corporation Celeron N3350/Pentium N4200/Atom E3900 Series Audio Cluster
        Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 25
        Memory at c2b18000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
        Memory at c2900000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=1M]
        Capabilities: <access denied>
        Kernel driver in use: snd_soc_skl
        Kernel modules: snd_hda_intel, snd_soc_skl, snd_sof_pci_intel_apl
```

But on sound settings page, only the dummy device shows up; 'no hw output devices are available'.

Similarly with aplay:

```
jasper@crbook1:~$ aplay -l
aplay: device_list:274: no soundcards found...
```

Tried running
`sudo alsa force-reload`.

Tried `sudo modprobe` for the listed kernel modules.

edit:

release

```
jasper@crbook1:~$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS
Release:        22.04
Codename:       jammy
```

kernel

```
jasper@crbook1:~$ uname -r
5.15.0-43-generic
```

edit2:

tried this: https://askubuntu.com/a/1225499/1620222

no luck

edit3:

dmesg shows

```
jasper@crbook1:~$ sudo dmesg | grep snd
[    6.105188] snd_hda_intel 0000:00:0e.0: DSP detected with PCI class/subclass/prog-if info 0x040100
[    7.855831] snd_soc_skl 0000:00:0e.0: DSP detected with PCI class/subclass/prog-if info 0x040100
[    8.745867] snd_soc_skl 0000:00:0e.0: bound 0000:00:02.0 (ops i915_audio_component_bind_ops [i915])
[    8.869331] snd_soc_skl 0000:00:0e.0: Direct firmware load for 5a98-coral-coral-33-tplg.bin failed with error -2
[    8.869345] snd_soc_skl 0000:00:0e.0: tplg fw 5a98-coral-coral-33-tplg.bin load failed with -2, trying alternative tplg name bxt_da7219_mx98357a-tplg.bin
[    8.869611] snd_soc_skl 0000:00:0e.0: Direct firmware load for bxt_da7219_mx98357a-tplg.bin failed with error -2
[    8.869615] snd_soc_skl 0000:00:0e.0: tplg bxt_da7219_mx98357a-tplg.bin failed with -2, falling back to dfw_sst.bin
[    8.869852] snd_soc_skl 0000:00:0e.0: Direct firmware load for dfw_sst.bin failed with error -2
[    8.869856] snd_soc_skl 0000:00:0e.0: Fallback tplg fw dfw_sst.bin load failed with -2
[    8.869858] snd_soc_skl 0000:00:0e.0: Failed to init topology!
[    8.869860] snd_soc_skl 0000:00:0e.0: ASoC: error at snd_soc_component_probe on 0000:00:0e.0: -2
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to install Chromebook audio drivers in Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1486278/how-to-install-chromebook-audio-drivers-in-ubuntu)

Answer (score 0):

There is a [audio-script](https://github.com/eupnea-linux/audio-scripts) repository for Chromebooks, which works for Ubuntu 22.10 and later versions. I have tested that it works on Ubuntu and Kubuntu 23.04.

```
git clone https://github.com/eupnea-linux/audio-scripts
cd audio-scripts
./setup-audio
```

And reboot.

Answer (score 0):

The repo mentioned in [Archisman Panigrahi's answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1469541/618353) was deleted, but based on the owner's name, I found another project (similar/same) that worked for me on Lubuntu 23.10/Chromebook Lenovo 500e. This is the repository:
https://github.com/WeirdTreeThing/chromebook-linux-audio

To install the script, open a terminal and run:

```
git clone https://github.com/WeirdTreeThing/chromebook-linux-audio
cd chromebook-linux-audio
./setup-audio
```