# Audio input is broken in Kubuntu 23.04

Tags: grub2, sound, kubuntu, pulseaudio, kde

I've changed to Kubuntu pretty recently, but for some reason it never detected my headphone's microphone, i've tried a lot of things, but i think i broke my GRUB accidentally following a solution i saw in [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1225463/18-04-no-sound-intel-sound-card-snd-hda-intel-not-working).

I did this:

```
You will need to add an option on GRUB.

To edit grub options:

sudo nano /etc/default/grub

Find GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT and add snd_hda_intel.dmic_detect=0 to the end of it. It will look something like this:

GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="loglevel=3 snd_hda_intel.dmic_detect=0"

Then rebuild grub menu:

sudo grub-mkconfig -o /boot/grub/grub.cfg

After you reboot the system the device should work.
```

But after i did it, everything related to audio input directly stopped working, when i go to `PulseAudio Volume Control`, all i see about audio input is unplugged or unavailable.

### What i've done?

- I tried restarting my machine multiple times.
- Un-doing all the changes i did in GRUB